# Static page and posts page

Tags: php, wordpress, url, pagination, html

Actually, we use the "Last Posts" option for our home page blog.
And we have this kind of url :

```
http://www.example.com/page/52 (show the page 52)
http://www.example.com/page/10 (show the page 10)
```

etc.

We would like change home page for a *static page*. But when we make this setting, the previous URLs stop working and show home page only:

```
http://www.example.com/page/52 (home page, not the page 52)
http://www.example.com/page/10 (home page, not the page 10)
```

How can I use a static page and keep "/page/xx" still working?
Is it possible? It's really important for our SEO

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin, and just set all child pages of 'page/' redirect to the home page:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/